# Calculation of Lorentz force in python and reshape elements

Tags: python, arrays, plot, reshape, physics

I have a problem measuring the Lorentz Force in python. I have the programm down below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define the x and y coordinates for the grid
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)

# Create a meshgrid from the x and y coordinates
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Define the magnetic field components
def magnetic_field(X,Y): 
    Bx = -Y
    By = X
    B= np.array([Bx,By])
    grad_B = np.gradient(B,axis=-1)
    return Bx, By, grad_B

Bx, By, grad_B = magnetic_field(X, Y)

Pm=np.linalg.norm(np.array([Bx, By]),axis=0)**2/(8*np.pi)


# Create a plot of the magnetic field vectors
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
strm = ax.streamplot(X, Y, Bx, By, color=Pm, linewidth=1.5, density=1.5, arrowstyle='->', arrowsize=1.5, integration_direction='both', start_points=np.array([[-4, -4], [-3, -3], [-2, -2], [-1,-1]]), minlength=0.1, maxlength=10, broken_streamlines= False)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines)


# Add labels and title to the plot
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Magnetic field lines')
plt.show()

B_dot_grad_B = Bx * grad_B[0]  +  By * grad_B[1]

Tm = B_dot_grad_B / (4 * np.pi)
```

I want to calculate the Lorentz force by the type " F= -nablaPm + Tm "
I want the Lorentz force to be in an array (20,20), depends on (x,y). How can I do it?

I try to make it as

```
Pm = np.array(Pm)

gradient_Pm = np.gradient(Pm)

grad_Pm = \[-g for g in gradient_Pm\]

F_Lorentz_x = grad_Pm\[0\] + Tm
F_Lorentz_y = grad_Pm\[1\]

F_Lorentz = np.zeros((20, 20, 2))
F_Lorentz\[:,:,0\] = F_Lorentz_x
F_Lorentz\[:,:,1\] = F_Lorentz_y

F_Lorentz_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(F_Lorentz, axis=2)\
```

But it doesn't plot correct along x and along y so I think its wrong.